# ubuntu mono font hanging emacs?

Tags: faces, fonts

I think this may be as much a problem with the fonts as with emacs.

I've been using [Ubuntu's mono font](https://design.ubuntu.com/font/) for emacs, and activating with:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Ubuntu Mono")
```

However, I can reliably get emacs to hang:

1. Set the font with `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Ubuntu Mono")`.
2. In any buffer (including `*scratch*` of a freshly-started emacs)
3. Do a `query-replace`, it does not matter if anything is found or replaced.
4. Do another `query-replace`. This time, emacs should provide the previous search/replace as default, something ala:

   ```
   Query replace (foo --> bar): _
   ```

   where the `-->` is actually a fancy arrow, not dash-dash-greaterthan. **Emacs *always* slows down a little in this part.**
5. Interrupt (`C-g`) before completing the act. Emacs hangs (for me).

If I do not set the font (fresh emacs) or set it to another font (e.g., "Consolas"), no such slow-down or hang occurs with the same steps.

If the font is somehow incomplete or incompatible, is there a way to make emacs more resilient to the problem? (Besides, of course, not using that font.)

Versions: win10_64, emacs-25.2.1 (vgoulet's 25.2mod3), ubuntu mono 0.80 (dtd 2011; non-mono fonts are 0.83 from 2015)

Comment: If you can reliably get Emacs to hang, especially when starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file), then file an Emacs bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If you cannot do that then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Submitted. I thought to ask here first, in case somebody else has seen it and/or could identify a simple thing I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's good to ask here first. You still might get a useful answer.

Comment: For troubleshooting and potentially as a workaround (depending on the result of the troubleshooting), you might want to customise the value of the query replace separator — e.g. use ` -> ` (literally), rather than ` → `  `(setq query-replace-from-to-separator " -> ")` or via `M-x customize-variable RET query-replace-from-to-separator`. [Stackexchange is inexplicably messing up my formatting — it works if I try it as an answer.]

Comment: You know, that's another question I was considering asking but wasn't certain how best to ask/phrase it. Thanks, @aplaice! I'll check it out in a few...

Comment: That fixes things, @aplaice. ([The filed bug](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=30291), if you're curious.) If you'd like, feel free to submit as an answer.